# Difference between gerunds and nouns ending in -tion

Tags: meaning, nouns, gerunds

As we know, gerunds have the same function as nouns and can be substitute in noun phrases. Additionally as far as I know, meaning of them would be *the act of doing that verb*. (I don't know whether this is correct or not, this is my intuition though.)

- Creating : An activity in which we are creating something.
- Cleaning : An activity in which we are cleaning something.

In the other side, we have noun "Creation" with meaning:

> the act of creating something, or the thing that is created:
>
> <sub>**Source:** Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary 4th edition</sub>

However, we don't have noun "clean + tion = cleanation". My questions:

- Why don't some verbs have "-tion" nouns?
- What is difference of meaning between gerund and "-tion" nouns? (for example: transformation and transforming)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gerund refers to the act or process of doing something - the activity itself and nothing further.

The *-ion* form of a root *can* mean the act of doing something, but usually leans toward meaning its result, effect, or manifestation - something that persists or evidences after the activity.

> Why don't some verbs have "-tion" nouns?

This may be a better question for https://english.stackexchange.com, but briefly looking into it, *-ion* [comes from Latin](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ion) and is generally used with words of Latin origin.  Non-Latin words - such as those that are part of the Germanic "core" of English (e.g. all the irregular verbs) won't work with *-ion*.