# Are both these sentences grammarically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

How is **self-isolating** coming along?

How is **self-isolation** coming along?

Are both these sentences grammatically correct?
And if one isn't, why?

Comment: The first is not incorrect, but the second one flows better because it contains only one -ing word. The first contains a gerund and a participle.

Comment: You could of given this as the answer.

Comment: @GWarner I could *have* given it as an answer, but chose not to.

Answer (score 1):

we use "come along" to refer to the progress or state of something, as in "how's the project coming along" (how much progress have you made on the movie?/ what state or phrase is the project in?) so as you can see we need a noun in a question like that (like project, baby, etc)

we can make the noun out of a gerund (isolating) or using a suffix (isolation) but which one works better here? let's see

> The gerund refers to the act or process of doing something - the activity itself and nothing further.
>
> The -ion form of a root can mean the act of doing something, but usually leans toward meaning its result, effect, or manifestation - something that persists or evidences after the activity.

(ref: [Difference between gerunds and nouns ending in -tion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73495/difference-between-gerunds-and-nouns-ending-in-tion))

so do we mean "the act of isolating oneself along with its results and effects" or the "process" of isolation alone? the answer would be the former, hence the reason why -ion suffix works better here.